# ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC passing argument to authorization policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-authorization

So we all are more or less familiar with authorization in ASP.Net MVC and the new [policy based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) where the most commonly used example is a policy called `atLeast21` which grants access to a specific resource only to users 21 years old or older.

But what if I wanted the policy to be used for multiple ages and pass the age as a parameter like in the following example:

```
[Authorize("AtLeast", new { age = 21 })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //some code here
    return View();
}

[Authorize("AtLeast", new { age = 25 })]
public IActionResult Index2()
{
    //some code here
    return View();
}
```

This way I could use the same policy (`AtLeast`) multiple times and won't have to create a policy for every single age I want to check.

So, of course there aren't many use cases for this if we are talking about restricting the age of a user but it definitely has many use cases if I want to say have multiple actions in a controller and one is for employees working in the company for 1 year, one is for employees working more than one year, one is for employees working more than 5 years in the company and so on and many more use cases.

Unfortunately I couldn't find much information about this in the web, this is why I am asking if this is achievable at all in ASP.Net MVC in one way or another or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create parameterized authorize attribute. Please look at this example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2
It is based on the same policy you have used.

Comment: This seems to work - Thanks, but can I use a Custom Authorization Policy Provider in razor view? E.g. display several stuff only to users of specific employment time on the same page? With Role based authorization I could say `@if (User.IsInRole("SomeRole"))` and also for the regular policy based authorization there seems to be an [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x) but how about custom policy provider?